# Connecting AWS GLUE to an Oracle database outside RDS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, oracle, aws-glue

I can't find a solution to connect glue to one of my Oracle database (Not IN RDS) .
with a lambda the connection works fine, which confirms that the VPC configuration is ok

I try to create the connection with Glue and do test, I got this error message
with JDBC ojdbc8.jar

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8/21.5.0.0

i get this message

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.exception.CommandExecutorException: Running Container Test:
      at com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.main.MainStartup.main(MainStartup.java:60)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.exception.CommandExecutorException: com.amazonaws.services.glue.exceptions.InvalidInputException: Testing connections with custom drivers is not currently supported.
      at com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.jdbc.JdbcCommandArgumentsUtil.getJdbcArguments(JdbcCommandArgumentsUtil.java:106)
      at com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.jdbc.JdbcCommandExecutor.execute(JdbcCommandExecutor.java:61)
      at com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.main.MainStartup.main(MainStartup.java:46)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.glue.exceptions.InvalidInputException: Testing connections with custom drivers is not currently supported.
      at com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.jdbc.JdbcCommandArgumentsUtil.handleCustomDrivers(JdbcCommandArgumentsUtil.java:293)
      at com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.jdbc.JdbcCommandArgumentsUtil.getJdbcArgumentsFromCatalog(JdbcCommandArgumentsUtil.java:157)
      at com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.jdbc.JdbcCommandArgumentsUtil.getJdbcArguments(JdbcCommandArgumentsUtil.java:101)
      ... 2 more
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also , I try with oracledb, and awswrangler not working --> I've only got mistakes

```
oracledb : RROR: oracledb-1.3.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
awswrangler AttributeError: module 'awswrangler' has no attribute 'oracle' : https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/007%20-%20Redshift%2C%20MySQL%2C%20PostgreSQL%2C%20SQL%20Server%2C%20Oracle.html
```

from what I've read it's impossible to make this Oracle glue connection?
https://pavan-andhukuri.medium.com/connecting-to-oracle-database-from-aws-glue-python-shell-not-possible-168cba968da9 !

is this type of connection possible?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please refer to this documentation for connecting Glue to various databases using their connectors - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc-home.html